# assembly x86 valgrind errors

Tags: assembly, x86, valgrind

I have project in x86 assembly (with some c functions such as calloc).
when I run the code I have about of 400 errors.
my errors are: 
Invalid read of size 4
Use of uninitialised value of size 4
and more.

I tried run the valgrind with --leak-check=full, --tool=memcheck, --track-origin=yes

the problem:
all the errors are "at 0x109088: ???" with some address and question marks.
the code is about 700 lines at all so I can't really copy here or something.
there is a way I can find more informative info about the errors/addresses?
how can I find which variable has the address of the error?
any clue how can I find the cause for the errors?

Comment: You can attach gdb and have valgrind stop at errors.

Comment: Maybe build your asm with debug symbols.  Is that a code address or a data address?  (I haven't used valgrind much).  Is it maybe treating your `calloc`ed memory as uninitialized, or does your code actually read uninitialized stack or heap space?